# Matlab linprog constraints: how to stop charge and discharge storage at same time?

Tags: matlab, optimization, storage, linear-programming, energy

I'm having issues with *matlab linprog* code. The optimisation function is the overall cost for the 24 period, just considering fuel costs of the boiler.

**Purpose of simulation:**

Optimisation of the charge/discharge behaviour of a Thermal Energy Storage (TES) for a 24h operation of a system consisting of a boiler, heat demand, and the TES. The price of the gas are time-varying.

**Problem:**

If the TES is ideal (efficiency=100%), I have no constraint that stops the system from charging and discharging at the same time. I CANNOT use one variable to describe charge and discharge. I do need them separated

At the moment I have the following constraints to describe the min/max charge/discharge rates (and of course some others):

```
maxChargeThermalTES>=ChargeThermalTES<=0
maxDischargeThermalTES >= DischargeThermalTES <=0
```

**is it possible to realise the following logical rule within the constraints of linprog?**

```
if ChargeThermalTES<0,
   DischargeThermalTES=0
end
```

all approaches, e.g. with a binary variable (to describe if the system is charging or discharging) do not work, as the binary variable always depends on the output of the optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can add your If-Then condition to `linprog` using one 0-1 binary variable and Big-M.

To realize the Logical rule:

```
if ChargeThermalTES<0,
   DischargeThermalTES=0
end
```

**Condition**: If ChargeThermalTES<0, then   DischargeThermalTES=0

Let's introduce a binary variable `y`

So we can rewrite the condition as

```
ChargeThermalTES - M y < 0
```

which implies that

```
if y = 0, then DischargeThermalTES must be = 0
if y=1, DischargeThermalTES can be anything
```

Let's split the `equal to` constraint into two inequalities

```
DischargeThermalTES < M y
DischargeThermalTES > -M y
```

If y=1, the above two are essentially non-binding.

If y= 0, it will force   DischargeThermalTES to become 0.

So with the following constraints combined, you can enforce your logical constraint to the Linear Program.

```
 ChargeThermalTES - M y < 0
 DischargeThermalTES < M y
 DischargeThermalTES > -M y
 y = {0,1} binary, M is a large number.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enforce such logical rule in linear programming.

However, what you can do is the following :

1\ solve your linear program, without this constraint. Get the optimal cost of your objective function (lets name it OldCost).

2\ Then change your linear program this way :

- add a constraint : old objective function should be between OldCost * (1-Epsilon) and OldCost * (1+Epsilon)
- the new objective function to minimize is ChargeThermalTES + DischargeThermalTES.

Cheers